# Calculations in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contains sub-elements that have several occurrences of the same element with different quantity:

Example array:

```
Array
(
    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11399
            [groupid] => 18
            [name] => Morphite
            [quantity] => 150
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16673
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Fernite Carbide
            [quantity] => 44
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16678
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Sylramic Fibers
            [quantity] => 11
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16673
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Fernite Carbide
            [quantity] => 17
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16680
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Phenolic Composites
            [quantity] => 6
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33361
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Plasmonic Matamaterials
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16681
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Nanotransistors
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16673
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Fernite Carbide
            [quantity] => 22
        )

)
```

What I want to do, is add all the elements with the same name / id together so that I'll be able to display one line with the right quantity.

Comment: Please post the array as text, then maybe someone can use it to test an answer, pictures of code are not liked

Comment: And please show us your attempt at coding a solution to this

Comment: Please show some code snippet as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple to do with a loop.

```
//create new array to hold new array format
$new_array = [];

//loop through old array
foreach($old_array as $value) {
    
    //check if $value['id'] key exists in `$new_array`
    if(!array_key_exists($value['id'], $new_array)) {

        //if key does not exist, create it
        $new_array[$value['id']] = $value;

    } else {

        //if key does already exist, increment quantity
        $new_array[$value['id']]['quantity'] += $value['quantity'];

    } 


}
```

Output from your example array:

```
Array
(
    [11399] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11399
            [groupid] => 18
            [name] => Morphite
            [quantity] => 150
        )

    [16673] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16673
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Fernite Carbide
            [quantity] => 83
        )

    [16678] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16678
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Sylramic Fibers
            [quantity] => 11
        )

    [16680] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16680
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Phenolic Composites
            [quantity] => 6
        )

    [33361] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33361
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Plasmonic Matamaterials
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [16681] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16681
            [groupid] => 429
            [name] => Nanotransistors
            [quantity] => 2
        )

)
```

If you want the keys in this output array to be sequential numbers for some reason, you can achieve that by using `array_values($new_array)` after the loop.

Comment: @IndrOp No problem, glad I could help.